# List of unnamed objects

Tags: python, object, oop

There are two bullet classes, a square-shaped bullet class and a triangle-shaped bullet class.

These classes have contrasting attributes x, y, x_speed, y_speed, dmg, etc.

In Undertale (search it up online if you don't know what it is), the battle usually consists of switching back and forth between the "bullet dodging" section and the "choosing options" section. For each bullet dodging round, which I will call BD, there is a different bullet pattern.

I want to know how I can effectively create different bullet patterns for each bullet dodging round by using these bullet classes.

I tried to create a list of objects that have either of the class's properties for each BD round. For which I can then call each of their update functions through a for loop. By a list of objects I would mean like if I wanted to spawn 10 square-shaped bullets and 3 triangle-shaped bullets.

However, doing so would require me to name the objects prior to placing them in a list, but this is not what I expect as I want these objects to be without a name and to just spawn whenever that list iterates through the for loop.

The reason I chose the list was that I could easily iterate through the list to see which objects have their dead attribute equal to true, which means that the round had ended. Their dead attribute is initially false and becomes true when they collide with something or their animation ends.

In conclusion, I expect to place "unnamed" objects of the two classes mentioned above into a list for which i can iterate through a for loop to update them on the screen and another for loop to check if their *dead* attribute is true. I want to create separate lists of objects as they will be the different attack patterns of each BD round.

Comment: "However, doing so would require me to name the objects prior to placing them in a list" - why would it require that?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of how you would need to "name the object" before putting it in a list?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to name an object to iterate through it.

```
class BulletRound:
    # Constructor accepts int for amount of bullets to spawn
    def __init__(self, bullet_count):
        # class variable list for storing bullets
        self.bullets = []
        # Generate the bullets and store them
        for i in range(bullet_count):
            self.bullets.append(Bullet())

    def tick(self):
        # Something you can call from the BulletRound object for updates
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.update()


class Bullet:
    def __init__(self):
        # Do logic for class attributes that bullets need here
        # This would be where you decide speed, damage, etc.
        # You can also make an alive property to check during updates
    
    def spawn(self):
        # Spawn bullets here or by some other method. Up to you.

    def update(self):
        # Make the bullets do things
```

This is a rough example of things you could do. Your wording was confusing and I'm tired but I figured I would try to help out